# How to Export SVG Icons from TypeScript Library

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

**Goal**

I'm working on a proof of concept project where the goal is to create an NPM package with TypeScript which exports custom SVG icons. The library is to only export the raw SVG's themselves, and not as a [framework] component.

**Problem**

Right now, I am receiving various TypeScript errors, either about an export not existing, or the library not having been typed correctly. Because there's not one specific problem, I am hoping to share some of my configurations for someone more familiar with this tooling to hopefully help.

I'm not very strong with tooling, so I am not sure where the disconnect is with

- Exporting the SVG icons to be imported by the end user
- Creating the proper type declarations for the library

**Configuration**

*package.json*

```
{
  ...
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src", "global.d.ts"]
}
```

*global.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

*src/index.ts*

```
import TestIcon from "./svg/test.svg";
import ArrowThinLeft from "./svg/arrow-thin-left.svg";

export { TestIcon, ArrowThinLeft };
```

Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: Are you using something like webpack to resolve the SVG imports?

Comment: @catgirlkelly I am not. I thought the tsc build would do the same? Should I use Webpack, or something like esbuild for this?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use a bundler, such as but not limited to webpack or esbuild. `tsc` is the TypeScript compiler, it does not understand SVGs at all. Bundlers themselves may not understand SVGs out of the box either so you'll need to use things called loaders, which are essentially plugins to help the bundler understand how to load a certain type of file.

Comment: @Yuschick did you manage to answer your question? I am looking for the same thing and I would love to check out the solution you found.